# Spring AMQP separate connections

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

We are currently writing a library that consumes rabbitmq events with spring-amqp.
This library needs to be used from some applications that themselves use rabbitmq with spring-amqp.
Is it possible to isolate the separate RabbitMQ Configurations from each other, so that the configurations form within the library dont interfere with the existing ones in the applications?
both would connect to the same rabbitmq cluster.

I looked through the documentation of spring-amqp but only found a way to split the rabbit configuration for consuming and producing events.

Answer (score 2):

Since `spring-amqp` 2.3 there's a [Multiple Broker (or Cluster) Support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/#multi-rabbit) which could be used to create multiple connections to the same broker. You can find a sample config at this link.

Also, you can take a look at the `spring-multirabbit` library (https://github.com/freenowtech/spring-multirabbit) which is actually the ancestor to that feature in `spring-amqp` and can be used to add multiple RabbitMq connections support to a service that already has a Spring-configured connection in a non-intrusive way.